# Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не выводятся 2-я и 3-я запись таблицы БД, а только 1-я, 4-я, 5-я ? И как работают {0}, {1}

Tags: c#, ado

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

// выполнение хранимой процедуры, возвращающей данные в табличном представлении

namespace CBS.ADO_NET.ParametrizedCommands
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // код хранимой процедуры selectEmp:  CREATE proc dbo.selectEmp 
            //    as select * from dbo.Employees

            string conStr = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=true"; // создание строки подключения
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectEmp", connection) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };  // закомментировать

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте скрин работы процедуры в менеджмент студии. А {0} - это первый параметр в форматированном выводе {1} второй. WriteLine(format, args..)

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, какую работу выполняют эти аргументы?

Comment: Просто подставляются значения в эти места. Это форматированный вывод

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду параметры в шаблоне проседуры?

Comment: Из скриншота видно что в результате есть как минимум записи с id `3, 4 и 5`. Так что вопрос не ясен в части про то, что 3-я запись не выводится. 3-я - это какая? с `id == 3`? Кажется, что записи 1 и 2 не поместились на экране.

Comment: Вы задали два вопроса в одной теме. Не делайте так. Нужно было создать две темы. Ответ на ваш второй вопрос: "Как работают {0}, {1}" - [Составное форматирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#composite-format-string)

Comment: Aziz Umarov, Да, это шаблон. Подскажите, пожалуйста как посмотреть код самой процедуры?

Comment: Roman Konoval, не хватает Василсй Лященко Петрович и Иван Белецкий Иванович

Comment: Alexander Petrov, Спасибо за замечание оно будет учтено

Comment: Aziz Umarov, "Просто подставляются значения в эти места" . Объясните, пожалуйста, в какие именно места и какие именно значения

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно понять  {0} в выражении:  ("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerNo = {0};", customerNo);  ?